# C++ Mobile App Development in Visual Studio 2019. "Unable to start debugging. Check your debugger settings...."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a mobile app using Visual Studio Community 2019. I created a new app and tried debugging it, then the error appears.

"Unable to start debugging. Check your debugger settings by opening project properties and navigating to 'Configuration Properties --> Debugging'"

I tried setting the project as  my startup project but the problem still persists.

I've scowered the settings of the project to look for this debugger settings, though it has some debugging settings, the error does not specify what settings is required to run the app.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've found the solution, and I'm gonna leave it here just in case somebody encounters the same problem.

You need to add the Google Emulator from the Visual Studio "Tools > Get Tools and Features..." then install the google emulator and anything that is required to install Google emulator.